# /proc/uptime command gives weird result

Tags: linux, terminal, cat

When i use "cat /proc/uptime"
i get result 10257.21 31389.01 what does this mean that my computer is slow?
how to read about this more can you recommend me anything?

Answer (score 3):

`/proc/uptime` is not a command but a file in a special filesystem named [`procfs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). The man page also gives the meaning of those two numbers.

> /proc/uptime
>
> ```
>           This file contains two numbers (values in seconds): the
>           uptime of the system (including time spent in suspend) and
>           the amount of time spent in the idle process.
> ```

I don't know why you think a file named uptime says something about your computer slowness but to just know the uptime it is easier to use the command `uptime`.

Comment: I wish the documentation clarified what "idle process" and "time spent in" meant.  In particular I find that enabling/disabling CPUs with `chcpu` `-e`/`-d` affects that value in a way that is not easy to explain.

Comment: Looks like the system uptime is in wall time, but the idle time is summed across all CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Just find my answer from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/cp7485/why_is_my_procuptime_left_side_uptime_smaller/).

`uptime` is measured in "wall time", i.e. the number of seconds that have elapsed since the machine was booted. The idle time is the time each processor has spent idle, so it'll be around 2 times higher than I would expect in my case.

```shellsession
[jzhang@centos9 playbooks]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).